# C# EF One to Many Optional Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this model

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public Guid? GradeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Grade Grade { get; set; }
}

public class Grade
{

    public Guid GradeId { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

The Grade property of student is configured as being optional.

Grade.Students.Clear() removes all of the references of this specific grade from all related Students.

Is there a way to do this to a subset of Students? I would like to clear to foreign keys on a subset of the collection based on a list of ids for example. Is this unachievable? I could clear them manually but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way.

Comment: You need to make `GradeId` nullable, then you can set it to null and that will remove the reference of that student.

Comment: ↑ what @Eldar said plus If you change `Students` to type `List<Student>` you could use [`RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-5.0). Or you could add an extension method on `ICollection<T>` and use RemoveAll (search on that, there are how-to articles for creating this exact extension method).

Comment: @Igor I am so stupid, thanks that's exactly what I was looking for. In my mind RemoveAll would be deleting the entities. Thanks.